# Angular Apps with their own independent routers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Let's say I've a very large enterprise app subdivided into several decoupled submodules (not be confused with angular modules).

I don't want to bloat routing in one place and want those independent modules (non angular modules) to have their own angular and routing modules otherwise I've to broadcast routing notifications to each of these submodules. Ideal if these submodules can have their own routing listeners or definitions.

New to Angular.

Module A

```
angular.module("navigation", ["ngRoute"]).
    config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){self.config($routeProvider, $locationProvider)}).
    controller("FoliosController", function($scope, $location){self.foliosController($scope, $location)}).
    controller("NavigationController", function($scope, $location, $routeParams){self.navigationController($scope, $location, $routeParams)});

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("navigation"), ["navigation"]);

//config part
config: function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/", {templateUrl:"js/modules/search/view/partials/navigation.html"}).
    when("/search/folios/:productId", {controller:"NavigationController", templateUrl:"js/modules/search/view/partials/navigation.html"})
},
```

Module B

```
var result = angular.module("result", ["ngRoute"]).
    config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){self.config($routeProvider, $locationProvider)}).
    controller("FoliosResultsController", function($scope, $location) {self.foliosResultsController($scope, $location)})

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("result"), ["result"]);

//config part
config: function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/", {templateUrl:"js/modules/search/view/partials/result.html"}).
    when("/search/folios/:productId", {controller:"NavigationController", templateUrl:"js/modules/search/view/partials/result.html"})
},
```

The module B routing is not working so I'm not sure if we can have routing listeners in multiple places.

HTML

```
<div id="navigation" data-ng-cloak>
    <ul id="folios" data-ng-controller="FoliosController" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li data-ng-repeat="folio in folios" ng-class="{active: isActive('/search/folios/{{folio.productId}}')}">
            <a href="#/search/folios/{{folio.productId}}">{{folio.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Edit:
When I first load the document, both routers are executed against /search/folios/:productId 
but then upon clicking list items, only the moduleA's router executes.

Comment: ui-router seems promising, multiple routes/views, I'm gonna look into that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it down.

ui-router allows multiple state & url router provider for different modules (angular modules) within a single page app.

Basically each of my module (software module) has it's own "angular module" with it's own routing engine/state machine.

Each of my modules (software module and it's angular module) receives and can respond to hash changes based on states definition. Even if they have been defined across, for instance if "route1" has been defined for another module, it will respond too.

Reason: Modularity and Decoupled Systems. Cool, the project is more organized now.

**Edit:**
It's a bad approach to have routing in multiple places, have it in a central location and broadcast route change to all modules.